# Slice function in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, slice

My scenario as follows: 
I will take string input from a text box and once user click on submit button, this will slice some of the character. Here's my work so far:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm2.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication2.WebForm2" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
        <title></title>
        <script>
            function Check()
            {
                var inputBox = document.getElementById("TextBox1").value;
                if (inputBox == "") {
                    alert("Enter your full name.");
                }

                var str = inputBox.value;
                var result = str.slice(1, 4);
                alert(result); 
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="form2" runat="server">
        <div>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Enter your full name: </td>
                <td>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox></td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td></td>
                <td><button type="button"  onclick="Check()" >Submit</button></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
            </div>
            </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Found my answer by myself, all I need to do is remove .value. It would be really great if someone gave me a little hint of how to write above js in jquery.

Comment: What do you want to do with the input text? Can you explain in more details?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve (in detail), and what does your current code do that is not what you want?  Would you please edit your question to add more information?  Thanks!

Comment: I am learning js, so I wanted to create something as an input text will be slicing to (1,4)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are. The jQuery code:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Substring(1,4)" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#<% = Button1.ClientID %>').click(function (e) {
            $('#<% = TextBox1.ClientID %>').val(
                            $('#<% = TextBox1.ClientID %>').val().substring(1, 4));
            e.preventDefault(); // prevent PostBack to Server
        });
    });
</script>
```